# Применение 2х скриптов в Google sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть очень простой скрипт, который я нашел в интернете:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet (); 

if (s.getName () == "Журнал") {// проверяет, находимся мы на Sheet1 или нет 

var r = s.getActiveCell (); 

if (r.getColumn () == 1) {// проверяет, находится ли редактируемая ячейка в столбце A 

var nextCell = r.offset (0, 1); 

if (nextCell.getValue () === '') // проверяет, пуста ли соседняя ячейка? 

nextCell.setValue (new Date()); 

}

} 

}
```

Хочу применить точно такой же, но к соседней колонке. Пробовал делать 2 разных скрипта, но по итогу работает только один. Прошу помочь в довольно простой, на мой взгля, проблеме.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const column =  r.getColumn();
if (column === 1 || column === 2)
```

Comment: Михаил, спасибо за ответ.
Но очень вас попрошу, если есть время и возможности, напишите, куда или вместо чего подставить ваш вариант?

Comment: if (r.getColumn () == 1)

Comment: Большое спасибо! все заработало, как необходимо!